# In Linux crontab, stderr of my program must be redirected, why?

Tags: linux, cron, stderr, sigpipe

I write a program, which can output to `stderr`. When I run it by Linux `crontab`, I must redirect the `stderr`. if not, the program will exit with a `SIGPIPE`. Why?

**NOT OK**

```
45 10 * * * /home/sandy/test > /home/sandy/test.log &
```

**OK**

```
45 10 * * * /home/sandy/test > /home/sandy/test.log 2>&1 &
```

Comment: It shouldn't. Can you post your program? Check @Lars Kotthoff response.

Answer (score 4):

You're running the command in the background (`&` at the end). This means that the shell that cron has started to run the command will not wait for its completion and terminate as soon as the command has been started. If your program now tries to write to `stderr`, nothing is connected to the read end and you get a SIGPIPE. If you redirect to a file, this doesn't happen because the running process knows where to write to.

The other way of fixing this would be to run the command in the foreground, i.e. without the `&` at the end. This is better practice anyway.

Comment: This is a great post. I feel like I should have known this, but I didn't. Perl was returning 255, and I just figured out why -- it was running in cron and something was using `warn`.

Answer (score 1):

`SIGPIPE` is sent to a process if it tries to write to a pipe (or socket)
the reading end of which was closed. cron normally tries to send the `stdout` and `stderr` output of the 
specified command via e-mail, except if it is redirected. It is 
conceivable that on your machine the local e-mail delivery is not set up 
correctly and the e-mail program started by cron to e-mail `stderr` to you 
died while `/home/sandy/test` still ran, causing the broken pipe.

Answer derived from [here](http://www.manpagez.com/man/5/crontab/) and [here](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=497492B7.3070003@isis-papyrus.com&forum_name=doxygen-users)